# Setting tableview to static still displays a lot of rows

Tags: ios, uitableview

I'm attempting to display a static tableview in my `UITableViewController` as I only want to display 1 row. I've set the tableview's `content` to `Static Cells` already but I still get more rows than I want to appear when I deploy it to my test device. I've also explicitly set the number of rows and sections in my `UITableViewController` subclass but still the results are the same.

I've attached some screenshots to further explain the result I'm getting.

Here's a screenshot of what my tableview controller looks like in the storyboard

[image: storyboard]

Here's a screenshot of the attribute inspector of my table view
[image]
[image]

Here's a screenshot of my `UITableViewController` subclass
[image]

Finally, here's a screenshot of what the tableview looks like on the test device
[image]

As you can see even though I set the number of static rows to 1, I still get multiple rows. I'm not sure why this is happening but if anyone has any ideas, I'd appreciate the help.

Thanks

Comment: This is the default behavior of a `UITableView`. There is only 1 cell in the table, but it draws horizontal lines to fill the bounds of the view. What effect are you trying to achieve instead?

Comment: @nathan I'm trying to achieve the look of the iOS Settings app. Apple used a static table view to present to the user various settings that they can adjust. I'm looking for the same behavior in my app

Comment: Got it. You'll need to use a `Grouped` style on the table view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the table view's style to `Grouped`.

This should give the effect you desire:

[image: table view screenshot with grouped style]

Comment: Thanks for the quick info. That worked! I've used Grouped style a long time ago and I completely forgot that there were 2 types of table view styles.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to `.grouped` style, if you have to use `.plain`, is to attach a zero height `tableFooterView` to the table view since it won't draw separators below a footer.

You can either drag a view into the table view in Interface Builder, or add it in your viewDidLoad:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()
}
```